# Como Posso fazer para Gravar um audio com AudioRecorder da API Android No Delphi Pascal

Tags: android, delphi, api, pascal

Estou com um pequeno projeto onde preciso gravar um audio pela API android através do Delphi com Pascal, porém não tenho obtido muito sucesso nos meus códigos. Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse dilema?

o que eu tenho é uma mistura de alguns exemplos que encontrei na internet e esta assim:

```
procedure RecordAudioFile(NomeArquivo : String);
Var
AudioRecord: JAudioRecord;
M : TMemoryStream;
I : Integer;
TAmpOn : TJavaArray<SmallInt>;
Okunan : Integer;
Begin
  AUDIO_CHANNELS := TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
  AUDIO_ENCODING := TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
  RECORDER_AUDIO_SOURCE := TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.MIC;
  RECORDER_SAMPLERATE := 11025; //8000;
  BufferElements2Rec := 1024 ; //want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
  BytesPerElement := 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

 AudioRecord := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(RECORDER_AUDIO_SOURCE,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,AUDIO_CHANNELS,AUDIO_ENCODING,BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

 (AudioRecord As JAudioRecord).startRecording;
 Okunan := 0;

 MyBytes := TBytesStream.Create;

 for I := 1 to 2 do
 Begin                                    
   TAmpOn := TJavaArray<SmallInt>.Create(BufferElements2Rec);     
   Okunan := Okunan + (AudioRecord As JAudioRecord).read(TAmpOn,0,BufferElements2Rec);
   MyBytes.Write(TAmpOn.Data^, TAmpOn.Length * BytesPerElement);
   TAmpOn.Free;                               
 End;
 (AudioRecord As JAudioRecord).stop;
 AudioRecord.release;
 MyBytes.SaveToFile(GetPathFileName(NomeArquivo)); //GetPathFileName Retorna IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath)+NomeArquivo
End;
```

A questão é que não sei se devo usar esta função em um loop ou timer, enfim não consegui resolver essa questão...